# discord.js How do I do that with the slash command from my config the names are displayed as tabbar?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to display the radio names from the config with a slash command. I have used this approach so far but only get this error.

The config from where the name shoud be read which needs to be tabbable

```
// radioConfig.js
const radioConfig = {
  "Radio 1": {
    url: "link"
  },
  "Radio 2": {
    url: "http://radiourl2.com"
  },
  "Radio 3": {
    url: "http://radiourl3.com"
  }
};
module.exports = radioConfig;
```

the code of the command as far as i tried to do it mysqlf

```
// playradio.js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const radioConfig = require('./radioConfig'); // Die Konfigurationsdatei einbinden
  

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("playradio")
        .setDescription("Play a radio station.")
        .addStringOption(option => option
            .setName("station")
            .setDescription("Radio station name")
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(Object.keys(radioConfig).map(radioName => [radioName, radioName]))
        ),
    // play radio and so on...
```

error:
Error:

```
errors: [
    [
      0,
      ValidationError: Expected the value to not be an array
          at _ObjectValidator.handle (C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1235:25)
          at _ObjectValidator.run (C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:202:23)
          at _ArrayValidator.handle (C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:474:37)
          at _ArrayValidator.parse (C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:216:88)
          at MixedClass.addChoices (C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1804:22)
          at C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\commands\radio.js:14:14
          at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:2129:50)
          at MixedClass.addStringOption (C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:2101:17)
          at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anwender\Documents\GitHub\DcMusicBot\commands\radio.js:10:10)
          at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14) {
        validator: 's.object(T)',
        given: [
          [ 'Radio 1', 'Radio 1' ],
          [ 'Radio 2', 'Radio 2' ],
          [ 'Radio 3', 'Radio 3' ]
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each choice needs to be an [`APIApplicationCommandOptionChoice`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/interface/APIApplicationCommandOptionChoice). That is, instead of `[name: string, value: string]`, it has to be `{ name: string, value: string }`. Also, the array has to be flattened, so you have to utilize the spread operator after mapping. The fixed code would be:

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("playradio")
        .setDescription("Play a radio station.")
        .addStringOption(option => option
            .setName("station")
            .setDescription("Radio station name")
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(...Object.keys(radioConfig).map(radioName => ({ name: radioName, value: radioName })))
        ),
    // play radio and so on...
```